# Dirty cow freezing

Tags: ubuntu, dirty-cow

I checked my Ubuntu PC  for dirtycow vulnerability, by using following code I downloaded from [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40616/). 
I compiled and run this code and run.When i execute this code using cc .

```
$ gcc cowroot.c -o cowroot -pthread
$./cowroot
```

It's got root access, but after few sec it freeze my Ubuntu.
According this vulnerability, it only give root access, not freeze the system.

But it freeze my system. This is why i posted this question here

More details:
 my `arch:x86_64`

Comment: You should probably add an actual question what you want to know, and much more details. If you want to freezing issue solved, you'll likely be required to provide a crashdump or kernel dump, which might not be an easy thing to fetch (and seems out of scope for Stack Exchange anyway).

Comment: https://www.flashpoint-intel.com/analysis-dirtycow-kernel-exploit seems to indicate that the two dirty cow exploit programs they tested, including cowroot.c, will typically crash the kernel after a few minutes.  So your experience is not unique to you

Comment: @JensErat I want to know why my system hang during , cow exploit vulnerbility testing process.That is my actual question.You already ask for kernel dump or crash dump , I used `linux-crash` with this instruction [linux-crash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe). But it was not generated any dump on /var/crash.Do you have any idea

Comment: @infixed yes my experience not unique, But i want to know why it happen.Anyway thanks for sharing above link, It very useful to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot really help you with that issue. Anyway, as I already noted I don't think this is really in scope for Stack Exchange, being very specific for a single system and too broad (and this seems also the opinion of the others having voted to close the question).